# How does AngularFire $save function work?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to update a group of fields based on the contract number input in, user can choose which field they want to change, and can set the value. my code does not change the record, I don't know why.I guess the reason might be the prop is not defined. The app is build on using the api of AngularFire, my code is as follows:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Contract renewal & Group update other fields</h3>

                <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="groupUpdate()" name="contractupdateForm">

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="washroom" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Contract Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter contract number so related fileds could be group updated" ng-model="contractupdate" ng-required="true">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="washroom" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Fields Category</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="productfield" name = "productfield" ng-model="fieldupdate" ng-options="f.value as f.label for f in fields">
                                <option value="">No filed selected</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="washroom" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Updated value</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value supposed to be changed" ng-model="valueupdate" ng-required="true">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >
                           Change group value
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The controller part is as follows:

```
$scope.groupUpdate = function(){
        console.log($scope.contractupdate);
        console.log($scope.fieldupdate);
        console.log($scope.valueupdate);


        for(var i = 0; i< productsInfo.length;i++){

            if(productsInfo[i].productcontract == $scope.contractupdate){

                var prop = $scope.fieldupdate;

                productsInfo[i].prop = $scope.valueupdate;

                productsInfo.$save(i).then(function(ref) {
                  console.log("group update success");
                }, function(error) {
                  console.log("Error:", error);
                });
            }
            /*if(i.productcontract == $scope.contractupdate){

                var field = $scope.fieldupdate;

                console.log(productsInfo[i].field);

                productsList[i].field == $scope.valueupdate;

                productsList.$save().then(function(productRef){
                    console.log("group updated success");
                    ref.key === obj.$id; // true
                    }, function(error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error);
                });
            }*/
        };

    };
```

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console for any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I output productsInfo[i].prop to the console, it is the expected value, but the record has not changed, may be I didn't use the save function right?

Comment: the strange thing is the console output "group update success", if the $save function does not work, then it will not return a promise, but if it has worked, how come no result has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

The second $save operation needs to be chained from the promise returned from the first $save operation:

```
var promise = productsInfo.$save().then(function(ref) {
  console.log("group update success");
  //return to chain ref
  return ref;
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
  //throw to chain error
  throw error;
});

var p2 = promise.then(function(ref) {
  //do more here
  //return to chain promise
  return productsInfo.$save();
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
  //throw to chain error
  throw error;
});

var p3 = p2.then(function(secondRef) {
  //do even more
```

When code is put in a function given to a `.then` method, the `$q` service waits for the promise to resolves before invoking that function. The `.then` method returns a derived promise which can be used for further chaining.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)